# how to make a function to switch on the value of attributes

Tags: javascript

hey everyone so i was working to make this calculator work and i had other ways to do it but i wanted to do it in a particular way

```
        <form action="">
            <label for="firstVal">numberA</label><br>
            <input type="number" name="firstVal" id="firstVal"><br>
            <label for="SecondVal">numberB</label><br>
            <input type="number" name="SecondVal" id="SecondVal"><br>
            <label for="Result">Result</label><br>
            <input type="number" name="Result" id="Result"readonly><br>
            <br><br>
            <input type="button" value="+" onclick="Calculate()">
            <input type="button" value="-" onclick="Calculate()">
            <input type="button" value="x" onclick="Calculate()">
            <input type="button" value="/" onclick="Calculate()">
            <input type="button" value="C" onclick="Calculate()">
        </form>
```

```js
var firstNum = document.getElementById("firstVal").innerHTML;
var secondNum = document.getElementById("SecondVal").innerHTML;
var Resul = document.getElementById("Result");
var Operator= document.querySelectorAll('value');


function Calculate() {
    var Sol;
    switch (Operator){
        case "+" :
            Sol=firstNum+secondNum
            console.log(Sol)
            break;
        case "-" :
            Sol=firstNum-secondNum
            console.log(Sol)
            break;
        case "x" :
            Sol=firstNum*secondNum
            console.log(Sol)
            break;
        case "/" :
            Sol=firstNum/secondNum
            console.log(Sol)
            break;
        case "C" :
            firstNum&secondNum&Resul==null
            break;
    };
};
```

my problem is on the switch as you see i'm trying to make a function that will determine which operation it will do based on the value of the attribute **value** i gave the switch statement **Operator** as key to check on and i don't know if im missing something or i'm doing something wrong please lemme know if there is anyway to achieve the above

Comment: `querySelectorAll` doesn't have a value property. It returns a nodelist. [Here's the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Comment: a) move the DOM accesses inside the `calculate` function so they happen when the function is executed (when the button is clicked), not when the page is loaded (when the inputs are still empty) b) you can't access the `Operator` like that from the DOM. Pass it as an argument into the `function Calculate(Operator) {`, like `onclick="Calculate(this.value)"` or `onclick="Calculate('C')"`. c) move the `console.log` statement after the `switch` block so that you don't have to repeat it in every case d) `firstNum&secondNum&Resul==null` doesn't do what you want

Comment: @Bergi the first one  `(a)` isn't clear enough please elaborate i passed the `Operator` to the switch statement should i do it in html like this 
`<input type="button" value="C" onclick="Calculate("C")">`  can't i just make the js check for me which value the attribute **value** holds by the switch statement and then operate accordingly 
the c) point should i just turn all of them to null with innerhtml

Answer (score 1):

Things I changed:

- include value of button in function call (alternatively fn(event) -> value = event.target.value)
- get the reference to the inputs outside of the function, but since the values of numberA/B change, get the actual values every time at start of function
- the values of the inputs are strings so convert them to numbers by prefixing + (alternatively with Number('str'))
- calculate 'Sol' inside switch, but set as Result only once at the end of the function
- in case 'C' - as an alternative to resetting the value of every input to an empty string simply call form.reset() and terminate function (no Result to set in this case) by calling 'return'

Suggested improvements:

- firstNum, secondNum, firstVal, secondVal, numberA, numberB - a lot of different names :) Better stick to the same term every time
- instead of setting click handler on every button, use submit event of form with .preventDefault()

```js
var formElement = document.getElementById('calculate');
var firstInputElement = document.getElementById("firstVal");
var secondInputElement = document.getElementById("secondVal");
var resultInputElement = document.getElementById("Result");

function Calculate(value) {

  var nA = +firstInputElement.value;
  var nB = +secondInputElement.value;

  var Sol;

  switch (value) {
    case "+":
      Sol = nA + nB
      break;
    case "-":
      Sol = nA - nB
      break;
    case "x":
      Sol = nA * nB
      break;
    case "/":
      Sol = nA / nB
      break;
    case "C":
      formElement.reset()
      return;
  };
  resultInputElement.value = Sol
};
```

```html
<form action="" id="calculate">
  <label for="firstVal">numberA</label><br>
  <input type="number" name="firstVal" id="firstVal"><br>
  <label for="SecondVal">numberB</label><br>
  <input type="number" name="secondVal" id="secondVal"><br>
  <label for="Result">Result</label><br>
  <input type="number" name="Result" id="Result" readonly><br>
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" value="+" onclick="Calculate(this.value)">
  <input type="button" value="-" onclick="Calculate(this.value)">
  <input type="button" value="x" onclick="Calculate(this.value)">
  <input type="button" value="/" onclick="Calculate(this.value)">
  <input type="button" value="C" onclick="Calculate(this.value)">
</form>
```

Comment: Ah, `.reset()` adds a nice touch! I guess `firstNum.value = ''; secondNum.value = ''; Result.value = '';` would've been closer to the OP's code though.

Comment: My suggestion for the variable names would've been to use `firstInputElement`, `secondInputElement` and `resultElement` to make clear that they're DOM *elements*, not  the numeric values.

Comment: Thanks for the remarks @Bergi, I just made according changes

Comment: @Corrl thank you for the answer it helped me , i was reading and within the last statement `case "C"` you typed `document.getElementById('Calculate')` is every attribute is considered an id or a class and also the inputs in aren't with calculate id but each on his own (firstval,secondval,resul) still idk how it worked got me confused but everything else is understandable thanks again

Comment: @HamzakH all your labels and input elemens sit inside one form element. If you have a closer look, this now has a `id="calculate"` via wich I referenced it in `.getElementById()` to call the [.reset() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset). There are various ways to get the elements on the page... Have a look at [this page](https://javascript.info/searching-elements-dom) which gives a good explanation and overview

Comment: I just set the form element on a variable as well, so might be easier to understand what's happening